# Experiencing an issue on my iPad Safari browser where the zoom level changes unexpectedly when navigating backward using the back button

Tags: css, ipad, safari

Experiencing an issue on my iPad Safari browser where the zoom level changes unexpectedly when navigating backward using the back button. The problem seems to occur on specific websites. Are there known solutions or settings to address this issue, especially when navigating back within Safari? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated